# how to publish a module in NPM with github source

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm, publish

### I want my repository can be installed like this:

`$ npm install git://github.com/ariellyrycs/testpublishnpm`

### what I did, is:

- **install npm and nodejs**
- add my information

  `npm set init.author.name "name"
      npm set init.author.email "email"
      npm set init.author.url "url"`

  - `npm init`. in order to create package.json.
- sign up on npm official page.

  - `npm adduser` and insert my information
  - `git commit` and `push` to my new repository
  - `npm publish .`

and then i had those errors:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "publish" "."
npm ERR! node v0.11.14-pre
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.2
npm ERR! code E403
```

Answer (score 2):

[There's already a module on npm called `ariel`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ariel), so npm is basically telling you that you can't publish because you don't have publish rights for that module on npm.

You might try choosing a different name for your module.